# Existence of a minimum for a quadratic form over integers

Tags: number-theory

Consider the quadratic form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ for $a, c >0$ and with negative discriminant $b^2-4ac < 0$. How can I prove that it has a minimum on $(x, y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ except $(0,0)$?

I see how to prove that it stays positive, but why couldn't the value keep getting closer and closer to zero?

Comment: call it $f(x,y),$   complete the square on $4af(x,y),$    gives a lower bound as a multiple of $y^2.$   Start over, complete $4cf(x,y)$

Comment: @WillJagy Is there a way to see a geometric intuition behind it? Or is this just a specific trick? Does it work for more general quadratic form (in more variables)?